# set state to update value in array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

this is my code

```
const [state, setState] = useState(
[{id: 1, key:""}, {id: 2, key:""}, {id: 3, key:""}]
)
```

i want to to change "key" state

im confuse
now im using

```
setState(
          [...state].map((data, index) => {
            if (data.id === state[index].id) {
              return {
                ...data,
                key: result,
              };
            } else return data;
          }),
        );
}
```

result variable came from result when i fetching data.
result is a random string

Comment: What is `result`? A string? An array? At the moment you're adding the same `result` to each object key. Is that what's you want to happen? Can you add an example of `result` to the question?

Comment: Also: `data.id === state[index].id` will always be true so it's not really achieving anything.

Comment: @Andy oh sorry im forget to define that. result is a random string

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure is always going to be in that order `data.id === state[index].id` doesn't really achieve much.

For example:

- when `data.id` is `1` the index will be `0`. And `state[0].id` is `1`.
- when `data.id` is `2` the index will be `2`. And `state[1].id` is `2`.

etc.

It just sounds like you want to iterate over all the objects in state and update each key value with that random string you mentioned in the comment section. There's no need to make a copy of state since `map` already returns a *new* array ready for `setState` to use.

```js
function setState(mapped) {
  console.log(mapped);
}

const state = [{ id: 1, key: '' }, { id: 2, key: '' }, { id: 3, key: '' }];

const result = 'random';

const mapped = state.map(data => {
  return { ...data, key: result };
});

setState(mapped);
```